# Freemarker / NetSuite Absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, netsuite, freemarker

I'm having trouble with absolute positioning in a Freemarker PDF template in NetSuite. Basically, I'm trying to position an address on the bottom of a container, but it seems to ignore my absolute position CSS setting "bottom:0px;" Below is the code and an image of how it displays. Additionally, I ran the same code in JSFiddle and it worked as I expected it to. Any ideas on why it isn't working or alternative solutions? I have to place the bottom of my address block at the bottom of my container. Thanks!

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td class="address" align="left" style="width:300px;">
      <div class="address" align="left" style="border:1px dotted black; position:relative; height:150px; width:300px;">
        <div style="width:200px; height:100px; position:absolute; bottom:0; border:1px dashed red;">
          ${myBillAddress}
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[NetSuite PDF Template clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YykRs.jpg)

[JSFiddle Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Fl7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this problem by simply putting the address content into the TD and setting valign to bottom - valign="bottom".

```
<td valign="bottom" style="width:60%; height:125px;">${myBillAddress}</td>
```